# Aptana Studio 3 dissapearing folders

Tags: aptana

When I create a new project with sub folders, the sub folders disappear from the parent folder. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Which type of project you are creating can you give images for that.

Comment: Rohan, I'm trying to create a new web project...Once I create a new folder (ie: testfolder) and create and index.html it just instantly disapears. Any Luck? Also it is Aptana studio 3.